# C Macro Function Error

Tags: c

I defined such a macro function in c:

```
#define NUM_FROM_DENSE_MAT (PTR, II, JJ, RROW) ((PTR[JJ * RROW + II]))
```

And I called as following:

```
/*io.h:141*/ float num = NUM_FROM_DENSE_MAT(p_mat->p_val_host, i, j, p_mat->row);
```

Where `p_mat->p_val_host` is a float array, and all others are int number.

But when I complie it, I got the following error:

```
io.h(141): error: identifier "PTR" is undefined

io.h(141): error: identifier "II" is undefined

io.h(141): error: identifier "JJ" is undefined

io.h(141): error: identifier "RROW" is undefined
```

Should it not be translate to `p_mat->p_val_host[j * p_mat->row + i]`?

Comment: It is a really bad idea to use a function-like macro for this. All you do is to create obfuscation and unsafe code, for no gain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the space from the macro definition:

```
#define NUM_FROM_DENSE_MAT(PTR, II, JJ, RROW) ((PTR[JJ * RROW + II]))
                         ^^
```

Your code was defining a parameterless macro called `NUM_FROM_DENSE_MAT`.